# CMake: Cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake

I would like to create a CMake project using `cmake -i` interactive mode, but came across the error:
`cmake: error while loading shared libraries: libidn2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I've been following the tutorial https://learnopengl.com/, but use Manjaro Linux instead of Windows, so wanted to use the command line as explained in https://cmake.org/runningcmake/

On research, most examples suggested adding to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I attempted this, locating `libidn2.so` at `/usr/lib` and adding it to the relevant path. It had no affect whatsoever however.

Next I attempted uninstalling CMake in the package manager, and curiously the command still gave the same error message, even though given it was uninstalled, CMake should not be recognized as a command at all.

I have had problems with CMake on my machine in the past, having been unable to install and link the CGAL library using CMake, so it may be a symptom of a wider issue.

Comment: Have you tried using 'which cmake' to see where the program is still installed and then uninstalling it at that path?

Comment: Thanks @user3147395, that fixed it for me. I'll post a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the problem after using `which cmake`. Turns out there was another set of the cmake commands that came with the operating system I found in `/usr/local/bin/cmake`.

It was solved by deleting the command files in this location, so the command files of the actual installation were run instead, which functioned correctly.